# How can I write a java program to check if a string is a substring of another string without using indexOf(), contains(), etc?

Tags: java, string

```
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
{
   String c = str1.substring(i, i + 1);
   for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) 
   {
     String d = str1.substring(j, j + 1);
     if (d != c) 
     {
        System.out.println("no");   
     } 
     else 
     {
        System.out.println("yes");
     }
   }
}
```

I know this is not even correct but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: `...without using indexOf(), contains(), etc?` - You need to tell us exactly which methods you do not want to use or which method you want to achieve it with.

Comment: well, taking a shot at the logic, given a string str1, you can check char by char of your other string for a matching char for the first char inside str1, then taking length of str1 and  the index from the matching char, you take the substring and check if its equal to str1?

Comment: If you're not allowed to use all those methods, then they likely want you to compare *character by character*, so you're probably supposed to use [**`charAt(int index)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-). Or maybe they want you to call [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), and then do the comparison *character by character* on the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean as you would do in the classical introductory programming exercise?
E.g. something like this?

```
String a = "Hello, world!";
String b = "world";

boolean contained;

contained = false;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length() - b.length() + 1 && !contained; i++) {
    contained = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length() && contained; j++)
        if (a.charAt(i + j) != b.charAt(j))
            contained = false;
}

System.out.println(contained ? "b is a substring of a" : "b is not a substring of a");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write a java program to check if a string is a substring of
> another string without using indexOf(), contains(), etc?

There are many ways (also based on which functions/methods you use) e.g. the following solution uses `String#length` and `String#equalsIgnoreCase` in addition to `String#substring` (the method which you have already used in your code). The logic checks if the subject `substring` is equal to (ignoring case) the substring of the same length starting from an index in `str`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(isSubstring("World", "Hello World!"));
        System.out.println(isSubstring("foo", "Hello World!"));
    }

    static boolean isSubstring(String substring, String str) {
        if (substring == null || str == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int len = substring.length();
        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - len; i++) {
            if (substring.equalsIgnoreCase(str.substring(i, i + len))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```